# Given a target sum, find if there is a pair of element in the given array which sums up to it

Tags: java, hashmap, complexity-theory

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class target 
{
    public static void hash(int []a,int sum)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) 
            map.put(a[i], sum-a[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) 
            if(map.containsValue(a[i]) && map.get(a[i])!=null)
             {
                System.out.println("("+a[i]+","+map.get(a[i])+")");
                map.remove(a[i]);
             }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int []a={1, 2, 13, 34, 9, 3, 23, 45, 8, 7, 8, 3, 2};
    hash(a,11);
}
}
```

I want to know if there is a better and more efficient solution that the above one. Complexity of this is n. Can I do better?

Comment: Working algorithm for this problem cannot be faster than `O(n)`, because you have to check every element in worst case.

Comment: For one, you could exclude all values that exceed the target sum before you even add them to the list. (Unless negative values are allowed too.)

Comment: Also, your code would return false positives for even numbers if their half is in the list once. Example: `int[] a={1}; hash(a,2);`

Comment: it won't detect repeated pairs

Comment: Also, the complexity is not O(n). A hash lookup is unlikely to be a O(1) operation, more likely to be O(log n), so we're looking at O(n log n) here.

Comment: @EboMike Why is it unlikely to be O(1)?Is it because of chaining?

Comment: @imaginatives: Depends entirely on your hash table implementation. I should take it back though, with a good implementation and the right set of numbers and number of slots, you *will* be close enough to O(1).

Comment: Your algorithm is not O(N) because the map.countainsValue makes a search through all the values of the HashMap. See my suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation misses duplicated pairs.

---

You could

1. sort the array
2. iterate from the start and for each element

   - calculate the required complement (sum - element)
   - do a reverse binary search (from the end of the sorted array) looking for that precise value
   - if found, remove both

*It boils down to the observation that, with elements sorted:*

```
 n1 < n2 < n3 < n4 < n5 < n6
```

*the most likely pairs are coming symmetrically from both ends to the middle. Now, the worst case is still bad, but at least you don't have the hashtable overhead*

Comment: I dont want to print duplicate pairs.

Comment: It is a O(n log(n)) solution and removing an random array element has O(n) cost.

Comment: @sehe: 1. Sort the array step is O(n^2) in worst case. Also if you go for qsort, it is recursive, i.e., it uses O(n) extra space in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, your sollution is not O(N), because the containsValue make a search of all values stored at the HashMap. To solve it, I made a different approach using your solution:

```
  public static void newVersion(int[] a, int sum){
        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();


        for (int i= 0; i< a.length; i++) {
            map.put(sum - a[i], true);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(a[i]) && map.get(a[i])) {
                System.out.println("("+(sum-a[i])+","+a[i]+")");
                map.put(a[i], false);
                map.put(sum-a[i], false);
            }
        }

    }
```

At the first step, it stores the "complement value" of each integer and at the second step it checks if the complement exists. If it exists, mark both pair as used.

This complexity is:

```
* O(N) for the first looping
* O(N) * (O(1) + O(1)) for the second loop and the containsValue and get.
* Finally: O(N) + O(N) .:.  O(N) solution,
```

Comment: Won't work for this case:                                       int[] inputArr = {1,2,3,4,5,0}; and newVersion(inputArr,4);                                        Output would be: (3,1)
(2,2)
(0,4)

Comment: Because it expects to have a sorted input.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following solution for this problem. The time complexity should be O(N) because the HashMap operations put, get and keySet are O(1).

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * Find a pair of numbers in an array given a target sum
 * 
 *
 */

public class FindNums {

    public static void findSumsForTarget(int[] input, int target)
    {
        // just print it instead of returning

        Map<Integer, String> myMap = populateMap(input);

        // iterate over key set
        for (Integer currKey : myMap.keySet()) {
            // find the diff
            Integer diff = target - currKey;

            // check if diff exists in the map
            String diffMapValue = myMap.get(diff);
            if(diffMapValue!=null)
            {
                // sum exists
                String output = "Sum of parts for target " + target + " are " + currKey + " and " + diff;   
                System.out.println(output);
                return; // exit; we're done - unless we wanted all the possible pairs and permutations
            }
//          else
                // keep looking                         
        }
        System.out.println("No matches found!");

    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> populateMap(int[] input) 
    {
        Map<Integer,String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
             String currInputVal = myMap.get(input[i]);
             if(currInputVal!=null) // value already exists
             {
                 // append current index location to value
                 currInputVal = currInputVal + ", " + i;
                 // do a put with the updated value
                 myMap.put(input[i], currInputVal);
             }
             else
             {
                 myMap.put(input[i], Integer.toString(i)); // first argument is autoboxed to Integer class               
             }          
        }               

        return myMap;
    }


    // test it out!
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] input1 = {2,3,8,12,1,4,7,3,8,22};
        int[] input2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] input3 = {2,-3,8,12,1,4,7,3,8,22};
        int target1 = 19;
        int target2 = 16;

        // test
        FindNums.findSumsForTarget(input1, target1);
        FindNums.findSumsForTarget(input1, -1);
        FindNums.findSumsForTarget(input2, target2);
        FindNums.findSumsForTarget(input3, target1);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class hashsum
{
public static void main(String arg[])throws IOException
{
    HashMap h1=new HashMap();
    h1.put("1st",new Integer(10));
    h1.put("2nd",new Integer(24));
    h1.put("3rd",new Integer(12));
    h1.put("4th",new Integer(9));
    h1.put("5th",new Integer(43));
    h1.put("6th",new Integer(13));
    h1.put("7th",new Integer(5));
    h1.put("8th",new Integer(32));

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter no.");
    int no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    Iterator i=h1.entrySet().iterator();

    boolean flag=false;
    while(i.hasNext())
    {

        Map.Entry e1=(Map.Entry)i.next();
        Integer n1=(Integer)e1.getValue();


        Iterator j=h1.entrySet().iterator();
        while(j.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry e2=(Map.Entry)j.next();

            Integer n2=(Integer)e2.getValue();


            if(no==(n1+n2))
            {
                System.out.println("Pair of elements:"+n1 +" "+n2);
                flag=true;
            }
        }
    }   
    if(flag==false)
    System.out.println("No pairs");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void hash1(int[] a, int num) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    // printArray(a);

    int top = 0;
    int bott = a.length - 1;

    while (top < bott) {

        while (a[bott] > num)
            bott--;

        int sum = a[top] + a[bott];

        if (sum == num) {
            System.out.println("Pair " + a[top] + " " + a[bott]);
            top++;
            bott--;
        }

        if (sum < num)
            top++;
        if (sum > num)
            bott--;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: O(n) time and O(log(n)) space.

```
public static boolean array_find(Integer[] a, int X)   
{
        boolean[] b = new boolean[X];
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                int temp = X-a[i]; 
                 if(temp >= 0 && temp < X) //make sure you are in the bound or b
                        b[temp]=true;
        }
        for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                if(a[i]<X && b[a[i]]) return true;      
        return false;
}
```

Comment: this won't work for [5,9,25,3,6] and the target sum given is 6, although it can't be achieved, it will still return true

Answer (score 0):

Recursively to find the subset whose sum is the targeted sum from given array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] biggerArray = {1, 2, 1, 1};
        int targetedSum = 3;
        findSubset(biggerArray, targetedSum);
    }

    public static void findSubset(int[] biggerArray, int targetedSum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < biggerArray.length; i++) {
            List<Integer> subset = new ArrayList<>();
            if (biggerArray[i] > targetedSum)
                continue;
            else
                subset.add(biggerArray[i]);
            if (i + 1 < biggerArray.length)
                find(subset, i, biggerArray, targetedSum, i);
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }

    public static List<Integer> find(List<Integer> subset, int startIndex, final int[] biggerArray, final int targetedSum, final int skipIndex) {
        if (skipIndex == startIndex) {
            find(subset, startIndex + 1, biggerArray, targetedSum, skipIndex);
            return null;
        }

        int subsetSum = findSumOfList(subset);
        int remainedSum = targetedSum - subsetSum;
        int i = startIndex;

        if (remainedSum == 0) {
            set.add(subset);
            return null;
        }

        if ((startIndex < biggerArray.length) && (biggerArray[startIndex] == remainedSum)) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(subset);
            temp.add(biggerArray[i]);
            set.add(temp);
        }
        else if ((startIndex < biggerArray.length) && (biggerArray[startIndex] < remainedSum)) {
            while (i + 1 <= biggerArray.length) {
                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(subset);
                if (i != skipIndex) {
                    temp.add(biggerArray[i]);
                    find(temp, ++i, biggerArray, targetedSum, skipIndex);
                }
                else {
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ((startIndex < biggerArray.length) && (biggerArray[startIndex] > remainedSum)) {
            find(subset, ++i, biggerArray, targetedSum, skipIndex);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static int findSumOfList(List<Integer> list) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int j : list) {
            i = i + j;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need not have two for loops. The match can be detected in the same loop while populating the map it self.

```
   public static void matchingTargetSumPair(int[] input, int target){
        Map<Integer, Integer> targetMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
            targetMap.put(input[i],target - input[i]);
            if(targetMap.containsKey(target - input[i])){
                System.out.println("Mathcing Pair: "+(target - input[i])+" , "+input[i]);
            }
        }
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] targetInput = {1,2,4,5,8,12};
        int target = 9;
        matchingTargetSumPair(targetInput, target);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily find if any pair exists while populating the array itself. Use a hashmap and for every input element, check if sum-input difference element exists in the hashmap or not.

```
import java.util.*;

class findElementPairSum{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the sum key: ");
        int sum=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            if(!hm.containsKey(sum-x)){
                hm.put(x, 1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Array contains two elements with sum equals to: "+sum);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```